# How can i get left side-navigation's menu links with service or list?

Tags: web-services, navigation, spservices, current-navigation

ı need the side navigation menus to show them with a new design. How can i pull them? (example: "home" "news" "documents"....(the names and links.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TO pull the items use Rest API.
/_api/web/navigation/QuickLaunch